# Adalm Pluto works on Ubuntu but NOT on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, rtl-sdr

I'm running ubuntu server and have tried installing libiio packages from both source and apt-get repositories. I can detect the adalm pluto sdr device with iio_info -s (as root because I have not installed the udev rules) but it does not assume an ip address (e.g. 192.168.2.1) like it does on ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

```
>iio_info -s
Library version: 0.19 (git tag: v0.19)
Compiled with backends: local xml ip usb serial
Available contexts:
        0: 0456:b673 (Analog Devices Inc. PlutoSDR (ADALM-PLUTO)), serial=104473b04a060006ffff1c00dd1f8473f8 [usb:3.2.5]
```

I've followed the instructions here: https://wiki.analog.com/university/tools/pluto/drivers/linux

The output of dmesg when the pluto is plugged in is this:

```
[380299.366375] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[380299.520117] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0456, idProduct=b673, bcdDevice= 4.19
[380299.520120] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[380299.520122] usb 3-1: Product: PlutoSDR (ADALM-PLUTO)
[380299.520123] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Analog Devices Inc.
[380299.520124] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 104473b04a060006ffff1c00dd1f8473f8
[380299.553556] usb-storage 3-1:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[380299.555040] scsi host4: usb-storage 3-1:1.2
[380299.555206] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[380299.555732] cdc_acm 3-1:1.3: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[380299.558342] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[380299.558344] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
[380299.560691] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[380299.569781] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[380299.570205] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[380299.574968] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[380299.578953] rndis_host 3-1:1.0 eth0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, RNDIS device, 00:e0:22:81:0c:b6
[380299.579489] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
[380299.583238] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_wlan
[380299.595374] rndis_host 3-1:1.0 enx00e022810cb6: renamed from eth0
[380300.582838] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Linux    File-Stor Gadget 0419 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[380300.583349] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[380300.584030] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 61441 512-byte logical blocks: (31.5 MB/30.0 MiB)
[380300.584266] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[380300.584274] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 0f 00 00 00
[380300.584510] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[380300.607978]  sdb: sdb1
[380300.623364] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

This is not consistent with what the guide shows from analog devices' wiki.

I'm at a loss here as to what I'm doing wrong. The device shows up and I have the drivers and required kernel modules (I check with lsmod). Any ideas on what would make this work in ubuntu but not ubuntu server.

Comment: I think I may have been missing avahi; i've installed libavahi* from aptitude but I still see no 192.168.2.1 adalm pluto device